# How to use the unix terminal pager `less` from within Ghci?

Tags: ghci

In ghci, when I want to view the help documentation, I type

```
> :?
```

The terminal responds with

```
> :?
 Commands available from the prompt:

   <statement>                 evaluate/run <statement>
   :                           repeat last command

...
..
.
```

but the file is long enough that this beginning of the file immediately scrolls off the page.

In the shell terminal, when viewing e.g. a man page long enough for this scroll-off to occur, the pager program `less` is used to make scrolling easy and so that viewing can begin at the beginning of the file.

**Is there a way to page-view such as with the shell's `less` from within ghci?**

Comment: I just found this. The comments below mention a solution. https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2y2f1p/pager_in_ghci_like_less/